# WF - myCustomType cannot be converted to myCustomType

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I got this strange error from time to time when an workflow is activated:

> Object of type
>   'System.Activities.InArgument`1[myNamespace.myCustomType]' cannot be
>   converted to type
>   'System.Activities.InArgument`1[myNamespace.myCustomType]'

I am trying to understand where this error comes from and I am thinking somehow a different version of the dll is loaded, but still I cannot explain why this happens and how this could be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a mismatch. One thing to check is hit F7 when you're on the XAML designer to look at the raw XAML and find your code activity that is complainig. The inArguments should have a type like `x:TypeArguments="local1:MyCustomType"`
Then scroll to the top and look at the xmlns declaration and make sure it matches the namespace you expect `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.MyCustomType"`. Also check for dupes in that list.